# Change Entity Framework database schema map after using code first

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-schema

I've finished building my blog using EF and Code First.

EF was running against my local SQL Express instance, with [DBO] schema.

Now i want to *publish* the blog, and *i have done the following* :

1. Generetade the scripts for the tables and all objects from SQL Express and change [dbo] to my [administrator] schema from my server.
2. Ran the scripts against the server. No issues, all objects were created an populated just fine.
3. I have modified Webconfig and added my BlogContext connection string to point to the server not local sql express.
4. Published the site.

The error i am getting is : **Invalid object name 'dbo.Articles'.** - where Articles is one of my entities. It resides on my sql server, `[Administrator].Articles`.

As far as i can tell EF still thinks im using the DBO schema. Although i have added the connection string to point to administrator user.

How can i change the schema that EF thinks it should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF will use `dbo` schema if you didn't configure the schema explicitly through data annotations or fluent API.

```
[Table("MyTable", "MySchema")]
public class MyEntity
{

}
```

Or

```
modelBuidler.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyTable", "MySchema");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for searchers: I am just working with EF5 .NET4.5, and

```
[Table("MyTable", "MySchema")]
```

does not work. Even if VS2012 shows there is an overload which takes 2 parameters, on build it gives the error: 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments.

But the code mapping works just fine.

Comment: Have you tried using `[Table("MyTable", Schema="MySchema")]`?